# Android 4.0.3 - Refused to get unsafe header "AuthToken"

Tags: android, angularjs, webview, cross-domain, response-headers

I'm developing a web application in AngularJS that will be both accessible from browser and embeddable in an Android WebView.

My team-mate developed a few APIs which recognize the user through a custom header "AuthToken". Those APIs are in ASP .NET 4.5 and he correctly added the "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" param in Web.config file.

The APIs expose the method "authorizeUser" which should allow me to get that AuthToken header.

If i navigate the Web App from my browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, Opera..) everything works fine.

The problems come when I embed the web app in an Android WebView: for Android versions greater than 4.2.2 everything works fine too.. but for Android versions equals or lower than 4.2.2 the custom header "AuthToken" seems to be blocked from the Browser.

It seems to be a problem of the engine of Android WebView (which is the same of Android Stock Browser).. i think it's perceiving the AJAX request being cross-site and so it cuts off my custom header..

I say so because I'm sure the web APIs return the token.

So I went deep in AngularJS source code and edited the implementation of xhr.onreadystatechange.. no more taking response headers with `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()`.. I tried to read them one by one through `xhr.getResponseHeader("<header-name>")`..

But when the `xhr.getResponseHeader("AuthToken")` gets executed into the Android WebView, in the Logcat I find a WebConsole log which says **"Refused to get unsafe header AuthToken"**.

---

**Have you ever encountered a similar problem?**

If you need more information or some code snippet, tell me!

Comment: You might need to look into SCE and setup whitelist to your API, otherwise all the unsafe actions are going to be refused

Comment: Could you give me any more information? I mean.. I tried to whitelist the url of my APIs but nothing changed. And in AngularJS documentation it's said "SCE only applies to interpolation expressions". My problem is not in an interpolation expression.. it's happening when receiving the response of an $http.post()